# PHP Pass Checkbox values and dropdown values to Next Page POST

Tags: php, mysql

Iam trying a solution in PHP/MYSQL where in there is a some country list with a checkbox. Certain countries have something called entities which is a drop down which shows Micro, Small, Large as a dropdown. This entity dropdown appears for certain countries only. I am able to pass the checkbox checked values to next page. But i need to pass the value of the entity selected in the drop down also. Iam not able to acheieve that. My code ie posted below. Here i need to pass the value of the drop down (select - entity_selected) also to next page:

```
<?php 
            echo '<table border="1">';
            while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_country))  {
            $country1 = $row1["country"];
            $entity1 = $row1["entity"];
            echo '<tr>';
            ?>
            <td><input name="check_list[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $country1;?>"> <?php echo $country1;?></td>
            <td>

            <?php 
            if($entity1 == 'Yes'){ ?>
            <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="entity_selected">

               <option value="Micro">Micro</option>
               <option value="Small">Small</option>
               <option value="Large">Large</option>

            </select>
            <?php }

            ?>
            </td>

            <?php echo '</tr>'; } ?>
            </table>
```

The Next page code is below to get the check box selected countries.

```
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
            echo $check;
        }
    }
```

How can i get the drop down values here? iam getting the checkbox (countries values correctly). Can anyone pls help me on this pls?

Comment: Can anyone pls help me on this?

Comment: No one to help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" action="nextpage.php">
  <table border="1">
    <?php
      $i = 0;
      while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_country))  {
        $country1 = $row1['country'];
        $entity1 = $row1['entity'];
        echo "<tr>";
        ?>
          <td>
            <input name="check_list<?=$i ?>" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $country1;?>"> <?php echo $country1;?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php
              if($entity1=="Yes") {
                ?>
                  <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="entity_selected<?=$i ?>">
                    <option value="Micro">Micro</option>
                    <option value="Small">Small</option>
                    <option value="Large">Large</option>
                  </select>
                <?php
              };
            ?>
          </td>
        <?php
        $i++;
        echo "</tr>";
      };
    ?>
  </table>
</form>
```

nextpage.php:

```
<?php
  $entities = $checklist = [];
  foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    if(preg_match("/^checklist(\d+)$/", $k, $matches))
      $checklist[intval($matches[0])] = $v;
    unset($matches);
    if(preg_match("/^entity_selected(\d+)$/", $k, $matches))
      $entities[intval($matches[0])] = $v;
  };
?>
```

Comment: How will i show the result? i mean echo? as of now its blankl, its not returning anything

Comment: Can you pls help me wid it?

Comment: foreach($checklist as $k => $v) {
  echo $v . (empty($entities[$k]) ? "<br />" : (": " . $entities[$k] . "<br />"));
};